# Can we use Microsoft.Phone.DeviceManufacturers namespace in official Windows Phone 8 sdk?

Tags: windows-phone-8

Who knows if we can reference Microsoft.Phone.DeviceManufacturers component within official windows phone 8 sdk? I want to develop a background service using ServiceAgent class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj208461(v=vs.105).aspx)

"This API is not intended to be used directly from your code."

So, no you can't use this for a normal SDK app which you distribute via the Store - this is a restricted API. You may be able to use this in an app which you load on a dev-unlocked phone.